# Forced to reload page after ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I've just got a jquery function working with my rails3 application. When a user clicks a checkbox on the page, it toggles the status and fades out:

```
 $('#complete_task_1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#complete_task_1').closest('tr').fadeOut();
    },
    error: function(data, status, error){
        alert('Oooops!');
      }
  });
});
```

Initially I wanted to use $(this) instead of $('#complete_task_1') but I couldn't get that working. Right now, it's all working fine.

My problem is that I need to reload the page manually after checking one box - otherwise, when I click another items checkbox, the js doesn't seem to be called. It's neither a success or error. There's nothing in the dev log either.

Is there an easy way around this??

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" better?

Comment: *"My problem is that I need to reload the page manually after checking one box otherwise it doesn't work."* Doesn't work ***how***?

Comment: Sorry guys, have updated my question Jx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Initially I wanted to use $(this) instead of $('#complete_task_1') but I couldn't get that working.

*That* issue is easy, it's because `this` is determined by how a function is called, not where it's defined. Since jQuery is calling your `success` function, `this` is set by jQuery.

You can tell jQuery what `this` should be inside that callback via the `context` argument:

```
$('#complete_task_1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    context: this,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
    },
    error: function(data, status, error){
        alert('Oooops!');
      }
  });
});
```

...or since you're already calling `$(this)` once and I hate to see unnecessary duplication, you can use the scope you're already closing over:

```
$('#complete_task_1').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: $this.attr('href'),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $this.closest('tr').fadeOut();
    },
    error: function(data, status, error){
        alert('Oooops!');
      }
  });
});
```

> My problem is that I need to reload the page manually after checking one box - otherwise, when I click another items checkbox, the js doesn't seem to be called. It's neither a success or error. There's nothing in the dev log either.

You're using an ID in your code, so you're only ever hooking up one checkbox (since IDs [must be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)). My guess is that having updated the status, when you refresh the page that one checkbox now represents a different item.

Instead of using an ID selector, use a class selector or a structural selector matching *all* of your relevant checkboxes. It looks like you're using an `href` on the checkbox to differentiate them, so none of the code changes except the markup, and the initial selector.

So if you wanted to use a class on the checkboxes:

```
$('.someclass').click(function() { ...
```

Or if they're all in a container, you could use a structural (in this case, descendant) selector:

```
$('#the_container input:checkbox').click(function() { ...
```

---

**Update**: Here's a complete working example (live copy):

HTML:

```
<table id="container">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-href="http://jsbin.com/amiruf/1">
          One
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-href="http://jsbin.com/amiruf/2">
          Two
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-href="http://jsbin.com/amiruf/3">
          Three
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Those URLs just reply with

```
Response 1
```

...or 2 or 3.

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#container input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: $this.attr("data-href"),
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        $this.closest("tr").fadeOut();
        display(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        display("Error");
      }
    });
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

---

**Off-topic**: It looks like you're using an `href` attribute on your checkboxes. That's invalid HTML, `href` is not a valid attribute for `input[type=checkbox]`. You might consider changing that to `data-href`, which would make it [valid as of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: Hi. Adding either this as a context arg or using a variable means nothing happens when I check the boxes. Sorry for the confusion - by reload, I mean that once I have clicked one box (and it disappears), I need to reload my browser to be able to click another.

Comment: @Jenny: I added something addressing your reload issue once you'd clarified. Regarding the `this` thing, check for syntax errors, that should work just fine.

Comment: My mistake, forgot the comma - context and var both work. Just testing if that's helped the page refresh requirement

Comment: Hi, Ok. I will work through your suggestions and let you know. Thanks again. Jx

Comment: @Jenny: I dashed off a quick example, added to the answer.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Perfect, thanks for the help. Not using a class was foolish of me. That's solved. Also appreciate the comment about using data-href. Many thanks, J